# RadSpell not displaying properly in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, internet-explorer-10

I have table that holds a `RadTextBox` and a `RadSpell` control. Both are in their own td tags but when displayed in ie 10 and chrome the `RadSpell` button overlaps the `RadTextBox`.
[image: Overlapped TextBox]

The code for the page is:

```
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col width="33%" />
            <col width="36%" />
            <col width="31%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <DescriptionLabel ID="dlNote" Text="Note:" AssociatedControlID="rtbNote" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <tel:RadTextBox ID="rtbNote" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="SmallTextArea"
                        MaxLength="8000" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <tel:RadSpell ID="spellNote" runat="server" ControlsToCheck="rtbNote" ButtonText="Spell Check"
                        ButtonType="PushButton" AllowAddCustom="false" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am using Telerik controls version 2013.2.611.40

Edit: I am not sure how telerik decides this but I have found that the span for the `RadTextBox` is having it's width set to 160px when the CssClass SmallTextArea sets the width of the textbox to 300px like so:

```
    .SmallTextArea
    {
        height:150px !important;
        width:300px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/input/radtextbox-resizing.aspx

This is the default behavior or the `RadTextBox` to fix this if you are using a CSS class is to set the WrapperCssClass property to the same class as the CssClass property.

It will end up looking like this:

```
<td>
    <tel:RadTextBox ID="rtbNote" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="SmallTextArea" WrapperCssClass="SmallTextArea"
         MaxLength="8000" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, so this is most likely due to some custom CSS you have on the page. Remove it and see if this is the case.
[image]